# How to preserve MLIR that was needed to compile mojo source code

Tags: llvm-ir, mojolang

How do you retrieve the [MLIR](https://mlir.llvm.org/) that was needed to compile a mojo source file. I'm looking for something similar to the [-S](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Overall-Options.html#index-S) option to gcc that saves asm files.

The mojo CLI gives no hint on how to do this, and the documentation is scarce on this topic, but this must have been possible, especially when debugging the mojo compiler.